# cwac-thumbnail edits base layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

In my project i use the cwac-thumbnail (Mark Murphy's ThumbnailAdapter)
It works very well, but now I need to edit the background and some other resource from the layout of the view.
I can only edit the layout of the single elemet.

Can someone halp me?

[git for cwac-thumbnail](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail)

this is a picture of the list 
http://i41.tinypic.com/k47dyo.png

I'm only change the layout with:

```
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Comment: As noted in project README: "**THIS PROJECT IS DISCONTINUED — USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**". I have not touched this code in *years* and certainly cannot recommend it. Please use something else, such as Square's Picasso: http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/picasso-one-dot-oh.html

Comment: thanks, but with this, i can't create a dinamic listview from the json file

Comment: Picasso is specifically designed to work well when used with some form of `ListAdapter`. Or try Universal Image Loader.